# mongoose model.save error crashes the node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my Node.js server is crashing while saving collection using model.save.
My schema has a unique field
how to handle error
my code is

```
register.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({ status:'Success' });
        });
```

how to stop crashing....

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement calls `res.send(err)`, and then it calls `res.json(...)`. You probably didn't intend that.

That being said, we can't tell much else from the code you have provided.

What is 'register'? If `register` is `undefined`, that would crash the node process.

Are you sure you have a connection to the db? Do you have any logging? Have you called `mongoose.connect(...)` before you try to run `register.save(...)`?

Try putting a `try/catch` around the call to `.save(...)`, and in the catch you should log the error.

Also, you can use the [uncaughtException](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) event, but you should still let the process exit. Ignoring the error doesn't fix anything.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: The Error was " Can't set headers twice". The problem was as you said in your first line response was going twice that's why its keeps crashing, so i added a return statement after res.send(err) now it will not go to res.json(...) and the response headers will be set only once and now it is running absolutely perfect :)

Comment: actually i solved the problem u post the comment...still thanks for the response... :)

Comment: user3785337 - sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes to give you a hint. I would have accepted this answer if I were you, it doesn't hurt in upvoting either. @Josh - thanks for the pointer, it helped me on a different problem.